# Request handler not working in GoogleAppEngine WSGI application

Tags: python, html, web-services, google-app-engine

I am new to web development. I have written the following python code to get input in a form and send it to '/testform'

```
import webapp2

form="""
    <form action="/testform">
        <input name="q">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
"""

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)

class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        q=self.request.get("q")
        self.response.out.write(q)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),('/testform',TestHandler)
], debug=True)
```

But when I am opening the file in my browser, nothing is being displayed. Why is it so?

Comment: are you running a server to run python code, or just using html file?

Comment: I am using google app engine.

Comment: Add any console logs

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your app.yaml file?